# Material UI Multi-Select different code value and visible value - show keys instead values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, placeholder, multiple-select

I am using Material UI Multiple Select based on documentation example. I need to save id of the selected option and show name, so I render object. When I used example from documentation with placeholder, i see ids instead names of selected. 
See: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxz5yqmrzv?from-embed

```
const names = [
  { id: "a", name: "Oliver Hansen" },
  { id: "b", name: "Van Henry" },
  { id: "c", name: "April Tucker" },
  { id: "d", name: "Ralph Hubbard" },
  { id: "e", name: "Omar Alexander" },
  { id: "f", name: "Carlos Abbott" },
  { id: "g", name: "Miriam Wagner" },
  { id: "h", name: "Bradley Wilkerson" },
  { id: "i", name: "Virginia Andrews" },
  { id: "j", name: "Kelly Snyder" }
];

          <Select
            multiple
            displayEmpty
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            input={<Input id="select-multiple-placeholder" />}
            renderValue={selected => {
              if (selected.length === 0) {
                return <em>Placeholder</em>;
              }

              return selected.join(", ");
            }}
            MenuProps={MenuProps}
          >
            <MenuItem disabled value="">
              <em>Placeholder</em>
            </MenuItem>
            {names.map(name => (
              <MenuItem
                key={name.id}
                value={name.id}
                // style={getStyles(name, this)}
              >
                {name.name}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
```

Comment: Documentation example - https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Select is just doing what you have told it to do in your `renderValue` function:

```
            renderValue={selected => {
              if (selected.length === 0) {
                return <em>Placeholder</em>;
              }
              // This will return a comma-separated list of the values.
              return selected.join(", ");
            }}
```

You can let Material-UI figure out the correct display by leaving `renderValue` undefined when you have selected values:

```
            renderValue={
              this.state.name.length > 0
                ? undefined
                : () => <em>Placeholder</em>
            }
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

It would also be possible to do a more complicated `renderValue` that uses your `names` data structure to convert the values to names, but this is only necessary if you want to do something different than the default rendering of the selected values (such as in the Chip demonstration).

Comment: Can you give me the same solution on multislect chips ? In my case also need to save the id show the name (as chip design)

Comment: @Lee I recommend that you create your own question where you can describe your problem more fully and include your current code, etc. It is not clear to me from your comment what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942512/id-save-and-display-name-material-ui-multiselect-with-chips)