# ID Save and Display Name - material ui multiselect with chips

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multi-select

I am using Material UI Multiple Select based on documentation example. I need to save id of the selected option and show name,
I have tried many ways but nothing helps.
I need to store the id and Display the value. Please help me with your guidance.

Here is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-margulis-0knh6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wondering about the same and the only way I found to make it work is by transforming the `array` to an `object`.

Here goes the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5cy6p

In it you can see how `names` is no longer an `array` but an object with the value of the menu option as a `key` and the name you want to actual show as the `value`:

```
const names = {
 1: 'Lorem',
 2: 'Ipsum',
}
```

This way you can access the value(the name) in `O(1)` time (if you are not familiar with the Big O notation gives this a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), this is way faster than going through the whole array looking for an object with the same id as the one you are mapping.